# How to properly model a booking system in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, model

I'm building a booking system where students can book lessons from teachers.

Features:

- Teachers provide their availability based on 30 minute blocks.
- Teachers provide options for the duration of their lessons.

  - The duration of a lesson can be 45 minutes long, 90 minutes long, and etc.
- Students book lessons based on the teacher's availability and the duration they picked.

**How do I model a teacher's availability given a booked duration?**

For instance, if a teacher is available from 1:00-2:00 and a student books a lesson for 45 minutes, the booking would be from 1:00-1:45, and the teacher is now available from 1:45-2:00.

My models so far:
[Booking models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTMlU.png)

Comment: you need a `teacher_id` attribute in `LessonItem` , `max_booking` and `total_booking` in `time_slot` you can track the availability of slot to the students.

Comment: timeslots should also belongs to lessonitem not to the booking

Comment: Can you talk more about adding `max_booking` and `total_booking` in `time_slot`?

Comment: Forgot to add but I have a `available` boolean in TimeSlot to show whether a time_slot is booked or not

Comment: A `LessonItem` belongs to a `Lesson` and it belongs to a `Teacher` so I just establish a `has_many_through`

Comment: for instance there might chance of taking a class for a set of students. and you want to open the slot for that much number of students, the slots should be closed only after the number booking created for slots.You can set the max_booking, and increment the value of total_booking whenever a new booking for the slot created. you can also achieve this instance without the attributes in table, but will increase the db request.

Comment: if you have a availability boolean its fine, but to achieve mass booking and  to keep track the number of bookings per slot you should either request db each time to get the count of booking per slot or you should have a attributes max_booking and total_booking

Comment: for the instance you mentioned in question, you should run an algorithm to generate dynamic slots when a fixed duration of booking is created, make initial slot 1:00 - 2:00 , when the student come and select lesson with a fixed duration here like 45min. update the first slot 1:00 - 2:00  to 1:00-(1:00 + 45min) then create a new slot with 1:45 - 2:00 , but this will be in FCFS manner and no students can book intermediate slots like the student have to book from 1:15 onwards and so on

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. But adding `max_booking` and `total_booking` sounds out of scope for my app because the max number of bookings for a time_slot is always one. Once a slot is booked, it is no longer available for booking. So a time_slot can at most belong to one student that booked it. Unless I am understanding incorrectly?

Comment: Good point about generating dynamic slots. I'll need a way to handle race conditions

Comment: can i put a scenario ??? what if a teacher need to take class for more than one student.A group class something like that

Comment: In that case I would implement what you suggested. In my app lessons are one-on-one sessions with a teacher. That's why a time_slot can be booked by only one student.

Comment: I guess I can use your suggestion, all the lessons would have a `max_booking` of one

Comment: exactly... you can decide the max_booking and increment the total_booking when a new booking for the slot is created.

Answer (score 0):

We can model like below so that it could be able to relate one with the other

**Teachers_Availability_Information**
Teacher_ID
Teacher_Name

**Slot_Information**
Teacher_ID
StartTime(datetime)
EndTime(datetime)

- So that we could map different slot time for the same person

**Student_Information**
Student_id
Student_name

**Lesson_Details**
Chapter
ChapterName
Duration

**Booking**
Teacher_ID
Student_id
Chapter
StartTime(datetime)
EndTime(datetime)

- Save the information that has been entered by the student

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with one giant timeslot (from 1:00 to 2:00), split it up in timeslots of 15 minutes (or whichever the smallest assignable part is, 10minutes?).

So now our teacher has 4 15-minute *unassigned* (aka free) time-slots. The first student can then just see which time-slots are free and book them. Booking them then means: assigning the slot to herself.

In that case I am not even sure if there is a need for a `Booking` or `LessonItem` anymore. Or you could still opt for some kind of `Booking/Lesson` object which `has_many` (consecutive?) `TimeSlot`-s, which then opens up other possibilities:

- several students could book a Lesson together?
- they could add some more information: a subject, comments, rating (afterwards)?